# Не отображаются UI объекты в Canvas

Tags: unity3d

Я новичок, с Canvas работал на интенсиве всего один раз. Сейчас делаю самостоятельно проект. Не понимаю, почему на экране нет сердец. Вроде все включено, что должно. Где ошибка здесь?
[image: un]

Comment: на том скрине что вы сделали, сердца есть

Comment: В режиме сцены конечно есть. А в режиме игры - нет. Скрин сделан для просмотра настроек Canvas.

Comment: `Canvas Scaler`.`Render Mode: Screen Space - Overlay` поставь.